# manuscript, excluding author names and affiliations

Tags: publications

I have a paper submitted to a journal of Springer.
In the submission process, there is a note that "attach your manuscript **excluding author names and affiliations** but I did not do it. 
What will happen in this case.

Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: If the editor decides the manuscript will be send for review, the editorial office will send it back to you, requesting you to remove the authors’ names and affiliations and to resubmit a blind manuscript. I would not worry too much. These things happen.

Comment: @Alice Thank you very much for your nice and prompt response. I believe that you are right.

Comment: @Alice, I'd suggest you make that an actual answer (and that the OP accept it). It will give finality to the question that comments will not. Comments are often removed. And Welcome to Academia.

Answer (score 1):

As Alice mentioned in the comments, the editor requests you to send an anonymized manuscript for the review process. The review is most probably [double-blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinded_experiment#Double-blind_trials), i.e. you do not get to know the reviewers' identity and neither do they know yours.

Be careful to adjust any language in your manuscript accordingly (e.g. "*... as we showed in our earlier research [1]*" -> "*as has been shown in earlier research [1]*").

For answers on why double-blind peer review is beneficial, [see here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105200/is-there-any-evidence-that-double-blind-peer-review-systems-are-beneficial).

**TL;DR This is normal, do as the editor says.**

Comment: The plural on "answer**s** on why..." is a stretch. Two of the answers are identical, the last one is a rebuttal.

Answer (score 0):

Any friction you cause in the revision process will in the end hurt you.
"They can't even follow simple instructions" isn't exactly a way of showing interest and careful work.
Having to ask *again* for a version without authors/affiliation introduces delay.